# simplescreenrecorder in ubuntu: the sound output isn't clear

Tags: ubuntu, application, troubleshooting

Issue: `simplescreenrecorder` in Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial: the sound output isn't clear.

Reproducing: I followed the instructions from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tEhOptc2Fg0&feature=youtu.be).

apt-cache policy simplescreenrecorder

```
simplescreenrecorder:
Installed: 0.3.6+1~ppa1~xenial1
Candidate: 0.3.6+1~ppa1~xenial1
Version table: *** 0.3.6+1~ppa1~xenial1 500 500 ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: $ apt-cache policy simplescreenrecorder  <br/>  
simplescreenrecorder:
  Installed: 0.3.6+1~ppa1~xenial1
  Candidate: 0.3.6+1~ppa1~xenial1
  Version table:
 *** 0.3.6+1~ppa1~xenial1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: remove and reinstall simplescreenrecorder right ?

Comment: i have reinstall but the sound still isn't clear

Comment: Set to PulseAudio

Comment: at my Mint 18 which is based on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial it works fine, did you upgrade system, or fresh installed? have you ever used this kind of app with good audio, it might be bad microphone

Comment: additionally, please look at https://www.onlinemictest.com/microphone-settings/ubuntu

Comment: What do you mean by  "isn't clear"? Can we get a sample? If you're using a mic, also try recording it via audacity.

Comment: this sample recording just a second https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4E4x6UmwnOs&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Never upgrade system

Comment: No, i mean upgrade system kernel, but package ever.